# SendMessage WM_COPYDATA msg From VC to BCB : Fail, but BCB to BCB : Pass

Tags: visual-c++, c++builder, sendmessage

I can't understand why sending `WM_COPYDATA` from a VC++ application (Master) to a BCB application (Slave) fails, but from a BCB application (Master) to a BCB application (Slave) passes.  I have verified the HWND in debug mode in both BCB and VC++, they are both the same value (0x00030BEE).

The following is my code, it's very simple

VC Master (.cpp) (32-bit)

```
char ss[] = "1234";
HWND hwnd = ::FindWindowA(NULL, "12345678");//12345678 = Slave Window
COPYDATASTRUCT copydata;
memset(&copydata, 0, sizeof(copydata));
copydata.dwData = 0;
copydata.cbData = strlen(ss);
copydata.lpData = ss;
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)GetSafeHwnd(), (LPARAM)&copydata);
```

BCB Master (.cpp) (32-bit)

```
char ss[] = "1234";
HWND hwnd = ::FindWindow(NULL, "12345678");//12345678 = Slave Window
COPYDATASTRUCT copydata;
memset(&copydata, 0, sizeof(copydata));
copydata.dwData = 0;
copydata.cbData = strlen(ss);
copydata.lpData = ss;
::SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)Application->Handle, (LPARAM)&copydata);
```

The only different between VC++ and BCB is `GetSafeHwnd()` and `Application->Handle`. After calling `FindWindow()`, the HWND in VC++ and BCB is same value (0x00030BEE).

BCB Slave(.h) (32-bit)

```
void __fastcall OnCopyData(TMessage &Msg);
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
    VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_COPYDATA,TMessage, OnCopyData)
END_MESSAGE_MAP(TForm)
```

BCB Slave(.cpp)

```
void __fastcall TForm1::OnCopyData(TMessage &Msg)
{
    ::OutputDebugString("123");
}
```

The BCB slave can get the message from the BCB master, and output the 123 message.  But it cannot get the message from the VC++ master.

I am very confused.  Does anyone know how to solve this?

Environment: Win7, Professional, 64 bits

[image]

Comment: The `WPARAM` value is not required to deliver `WM_COPYDATA`, that is merely a convenience to allow the receiver to send a reply back to the sender if desired. What you pass in the `WPARAM` is irrelevant in your example since your slave does not use it. So that just leaves the only possible difference being either the `COPYDATASTRUCT` struct or `SendMessage()` itself. Make sure `COPYDATASTRUCT` is the same size and alignment in both compilers. And check the return value of `SendMessage()`, make sure it is not failing. For instance, maybe UIPI is blocking the VC app but not the BCB app.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Really thanks!, it blocked by UIPI, i change the vc setting (UAC Execution Level) to high, and pass. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, you could instead update the slave's code to explicitly allow `WM_COPYDATA` messages to be sent to it from lower-integrity processes, eg: `void __fastcall TForm1::CreateWnd() { TForm::CreateWnd(); ::ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(Handle, WM_COPYDATA, MSGFLT_ALLOW, NULL); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Remy Lebeau comment, change the visual c++ setting or call ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx can solve this question.

[image]